# Is there any apps to use a Sony NetMD?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an app as well as drivers to us a Sony MiniDisc NetMD, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Sony tried to make this an impossible task, there's no guarantee you'll succeed. Your best change is possibly the [Linux Minidisc](https://wiki.physik.fu-berlin.de/linux-minidisc/doku.php) project, you can install the software from the command line (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter your login password when required):

`sudo apt-get install qhimdtransfer minidisc-utils`

For older NetMD versions you might need `gnetmd`. [There is a guide](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/sony-netmd-on-ubuntu/) on how to use it, but unfortunately the tool is no longer online.